# how to fetch the result of a query inside a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, fetch

Is it possible to return more than one rows and column in a single query inside a stored procedure or a trigger? and how can i fetch the data being return? do i need to use loop or some thing?

here is what i want:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trgg`;

DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER `trgg` AFTER INSERT ON tbl

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

 SET @result = (SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE field = 1 );


// i want to fetch the values return @result, is that possible? 
// Or at least only the column only, not necessarily all the rows,


#### rest of the codes goes here #####


END ;;
```

i been researching this for about a day, but still i cant find the answer,
is anybody here can help me on this

Comment: so it is possible to return more than one row and field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cursor inside trigger. the good example of cursor is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Declare cursor for your select statement. And in the loop fetch values of that cursor in some declared variable